# Excel table (list) that fills in specific values if present

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a specific task which I do every week for few years now and it takes a lot of time to do that manually. I hope something can be automated here.
Every week I gest a list like this (in random order):

[image: List in random order]

The list contains let's call them 'names' (col A) and 'numbers' (col B) in random order, every time different. And here is a difficult part: I need to take numbers and place them into another pre-designed ***CALCULATIONS*** excel sheet (with all the calculations behind the scenes). Here is how it looks like (example):

[image: Calculation sheet]

I can't change order of 'names' in *Calculation sheet*. I just manually copy in numbers every week and there are hundreds of them. Is there any way I can improve this process to get this done quicker? Also - sometimes I get 'name' which is not on the list. I will need to add it later, but that's a different story and can't be done automatically because there are many things behind that). 
At the end, I need to know which 'names' are not on the list so I can get them implemented. I guess there is a way of sorting my problem out using tables / lists in excel, but I ran out of ideas how to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am trying to play with VLOOKUP function. I guess it should be something like opposite to VLOOKUP to get this sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Index/Match`.  The below is on one sheet, but you should be able to use multiple sheets, just fix the references:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$5,0))
```

[image]

Enter, then drag over.

Then, wrap in `IFERROR([formula],"")` to hide the `#N/A` returns when there's no matching value found.

Edit: If you want a `VLOOKUP()`, then this would work too:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

To highlight names not on the list, use Conditional Formatting and set the FILL to whatever you want:

Formula: `=COUNTIF($D$1:$M$1,$A1)=0` 
Applies To: `$A$1:$B$5`

[image]
<sub>(Using `A1:B5` will highlight both column A and B. I just did `A1:A5` in that screenshot)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I've just managed to get this working... almost. What is really important is highlighting on the fist sheet 'names' that are not on the CALCULATION (second) sheet, as I don't want to miss them. Is there a way to do that as well? So in this occasion - "Kim" is not on the list

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski - See edit.

Comment: ( @PiotrCiszewski - If this works for you, you can mark it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Answer (score -2):

I've applied iferror + vlookup function.

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1;$A$1:$B$30;2;0);0)

[image: vlookup]

Comment: (This should be a new question, or at least an Edit in your OP (not an Answer))